# I have method that can change date format and return it but it gives exception

Tags: java

I am trying to display the log file in my application as i need for that i have to format the content to display as i require i firslt trying to display the date for which i can get content from los my log file looks like ... .

```
[1324649399] Nagios 3.3.1 starting... (PID=3751)
[1324649399] Local time is Fri Dec 23 09:09:59 EST 2011
[1324649399] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1324649400] ndomod: NDOMOD 1.4b9 (10-27-2009) Copyright (c) 2009 Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
[1324649400] ndomod: Could not open data sink!  I'll keep trying, but some output may get lost...
[1324649400] Event broker module '/usr/local/nagios/bin/ndomod.o' initialized successfully.
[1324649400] Finished daemonizing... (New PID=3752)
```

in real application data is display for every one and two minut so the content of above file show date/time which is in square bracket "[1324649399]" so i want to change it in this format "[12-27-2011 08:51:22]" 
   in my method i am trying to change the date first getting from string first then i would implement it for the whole log file my code is,

```
public Date Date() throws SQLException, ParseException
    {
      DateFormat Format; 
      Date date;
      String dat="1324649399";
      Format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
      date=(Date)Format.parse(dat); 
      return date;
    }
```

may be the date format is not like that as i mentioned but i need to format it as i  mentioned above and it just giving error of exception and nothing more
    Hopes to listen from you soon your suggestions

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1324649399 appears to be a seconds-based epoch value so you'd want to multiply by 1000 to convert to milliseconds, which is what Java's Date constructor uses, so:

```
Date expiry = new Date(Long.parseLong("1324649399 ") * 1000);
```

Comment: It Helps me in conversion it gave me result 2011-12-23 but i am not getting time ??

Comment: @salman-raza :are you sure you are using correct format to print date? you can use DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf("1324649399000"));
```

I found that value is second,so, you can times 1000 or add '000' simply. The result on my computer is : Fri Dec 23 22:09:59 CST 2011, I guess it is a right answer.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: i tried it but it keeps on giving 1970-01-16 this result for every input ??

Comment: @SalmanRaza Try: Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf("1324649399000")); The value is time in second.

Comment: It Helps me in conversion it gave me result 2011-12-23 but i am not getting time ??

Comment: Do you mean:DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
System.out.println(format.format(date));

Answer (score 0):

The date "1324649399" is not in the "dd-MMM-yy" format but you are trying to parse it in that format which is the issue. I guess "1324649399" is in milliseconds so create a `Date` object first and then call `format(...)` on `DateFormat` you created passing the `Date` object. If it is not in milliseconds then identify which format that is in and pass that format to `SimpleDateFormat` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pangea. You can use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) also for formating your dates.

If all you need is the time to print in logs, then i would suggest using [Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

All you need to do is instead of System.out.println(sometext) use,
Logger.getLogger(Yourclasssname).log(Level.INFO, yourtext).

This will print your class name from which you are logging along with the time. This also gives you the flexibility of changing the log level for different environment.

Comment: can you please help me of this logger use according to my requirement by using my code i am not actually getting it .. .

Comment: the thing i need is ti just convert the date in to the format as i metioned in the post it is not converting it by using "1324649399" ??

Comment: import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class MyBusinessClass {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyBusinessClass.class.getName());

    public void myBusinessMethod() {
        logger.info("Im entering myBusinessMethod()");
        // your business logic goes here
        logger.info("Im exiting myBusinessMethod()");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyBusinessClass().myBusinessMethod();
    }
}

Comment: The output for the above code is,

Dec 28, 2011 12:18:15 PM MyBusinessClass myBusinessMethod
INFO: Im entering myBusinessMethod()
Dec 28, 2011 12:18:15 PM MyBusinessClass myBusinessMethod
INFO: Im exiting myBusinessMethod()

Comment: I understand that you want to format a date. If that is your requirement then what Edge said is correct. But if you are formatting date for displaying it in log, then you should prefer using logger as I stated. Because print statement will cause performance issues while usage of logger minimizes/avoids it